# Windows Command Script for a java program to stop and start

Tags: java, windows, windows-services

I'm new to this windows command scripting.

I would like to run a program everyday from 7 AM to 11 PM. I want a command script to run a java command at 7 AM everyday and stop the same at 11 PM. And then next day again it should continue doing the same.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok. Show us what have you done till now.

Comment: @brano88 To be fair, he's asking the question because he doesn't know how to start.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/schedule-a-task this may or may not be useful

Comment: Thanks Crunch. As you said in your other post below, schedule a task doesn't have the option to end the task. I already have started coding in java to handle this, but wondering if we could do this in command scripting. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The windows scheduler posted in @S4beR's answer will schedule the start of the task. However, I don't think it can tell the task to end. You could even write this in your java program though. Start a timer when it starts, and tell it to end your process after 14 hours has lapsed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try windows task scheduler instead of writing a command script. Its very easy to configure and server your need exactly. Refer to this [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows7/schedule-a-task)